# OrderBy Clause prevents navigation properties from being loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm working on a portfolio website, where, on a product page, I want to display related articles from the same category.

I've created a method to allow me to pick a defined number of article, in a defined category, randomly. Unfortunately, when I add the `OrderBy`clause to "enable" the randomness, I'm not able anymore to retrieve the navigation properties.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Article>> GetRandomArticlesByCategoryIdAsync(int categoryId, int numberOfArticles)
{
    return await _ptitsBricosContext
        .Articles
        .OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Include(a => a.Pictures)
        .Where(a => a.Category.Id == categoryId)
        .Take(numberOfArticles)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

When I remove the `.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid())`, I rightly retrieve the `Pictures` related, but when I add it again, I always retrieve an empty list of pictures (even if I always have results).

I'm kind of stuck, I don't see why it changes the behavior of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the combination of the *random* order, `Take` operator and sub collection `Include`.

EF Core processes collection `Include`s by using a *separate* database query, joining the primary *query* with the related table.

Since the primary query in this scenario returns different records, the second query join simply does not return the related records of the first query result. The related collections might be empty or partially populated.

Unfortunately I see no good workaround for this scenario. Consider posting it to their GitHub issue tracker and see what they will say.

The only relatively efficient workaround I see is to modify the main query to return just the PKs, execute it and use the list as criteria for the actual query:

```
var ids = await _ptitsBricosContext
    .Articles
    .OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Where(a => a.Category.Id == categoryId)
    .Take(numberOfArticles)
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .ToListAsync();

return await _ptitsBricosContext
    .Articles
    .Include(a => a.Pictures)
    .Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: That was my second idea, was expecting a "quick fix" for my problem. Many thanks for your help and your in-depth explanation, I now understand why it's not working, let's wait and see if they will get if fixed :)